# Set InkCanvas Background DrawingBrush via C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, canvas, inkcanvas

I want to set the following XAML attributes via C#:

```
<InkCanvas.Background>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,2,2" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="White">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,2,2" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFE3E3E3">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="1,1,1,1" />
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </InkCanvas.Background>
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution myself and leave it here for anyone else, facing the same issue.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-drawing-brush/ pretty much is what i was looking for.